# Bash: get column of tab delimited row of table

Tags: bash, awk

`last | head -1` gives me a row of information about the last login on my system. It looks like this:

```
root     pts/0        123.123.234.321   Sat Sep 23 20:38   still logged in
```

I want to extract the IP address and time of this login using bash commands (maybe awk?) How can I do this? At the end, I should end up with `123.123.234.321   Sat Sep 23 20:38`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need not to use `head` along with `awk`, as `awk` could read the very first line by itself, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
last | awk 'FNR==1{print $3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
```

OR

```
last | awk 'FNR==1{print "Server login:",$3,$4,$5,$6,$7;exit}'
```

**Explanation:** Using last command to get the login details on system then using pipe(|) to use it's standard output as standard input for awk command. Now in awk command FNR==1 makes sure that it should run on very first line, so when this condition gets true then print 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th and 7th fields of that line.

**PS:** Also if you need to read only the last login then I believe you could use `{print $3,$4,$5,$6,$7;exit}` so that it will not read all the lines of last command and will be a bit faster too.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! Now do you know how I add text to the front so the output looks like `Server login: 123.123.234.321   Sat Sep 23 20:38`?

Comment: @quantumbutterfly, I have added solution after OR too now. Please check it and let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can take what you have and pipe it to `awk`, e.g.:

```
last | head -1 | awk '{print $3 "   " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7}'
```

Sample:

```
awk '{print $3 "   " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7}'<<<'root     pts/0        123.123.234.321   Sat Sep 23 20:38   still logged in'
123.123.234.321   Sat Sep 23 20:38
```

I put three spaces between `$3` and `$4` because that's what was in your sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
last | head -1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3-7
```

where `tr -s` squeezes multiple spaces into one and `cut` prints fields 3 to 7.